# Combining min-width and max-width

Tags: html, css

I want `div1` to appear only when the window width is less than 800px, and I want `div2` to appear only when the window width is greater than 800px. My solution is to use the following CSS which works. However, is there a way to do this using only one `@media` command? It seems clumsy to have to write two conditions, one for a `max-width`, and one for a `min-width`.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #div1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #div2 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  #div1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #div2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  DIV1
</div>

<div id="div2">
  DIV2
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take one of the set out of media queries.

```css
#div1 {
  display: none;
}
#div2 {
  display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #div1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #div2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  DIV1
</div>
<div id="div2">
  DIV2
</div>
```

Or

```css
#div1 {
  display: block;
}
#div2 {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  #div1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #div2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  DIV1
</div>
<div id="div2">
  DIV2
</div>
```

Comment: To confirm that the two Stack snippets work as intended, I had to click "Full page".

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to combine media queries try:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 400px) {
```

The query above will trigger only for screens that are 600-400px wide. This can be used to target specific devices with known widths.

Or if you only want to target screen sizes that are 800px or less use:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
replace @media screen and (max-width: 800px) { #div1 {
display: block;
}
#div2 {
display: none;
} }

with  #div1 {
display: block;
}
#div2 {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: I am writing as an SO reviewer because your answer has been flagged for 'low-quality'. The main shortcoming seems to be the absence of descriptive text that explains how and why your code answers the question. Please remember that your code could be read many times by other programmers seeking solutions in future and add some text that helps others to understand.